# Manually upload symbols to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, debug-symbols, azure-artifacts

We are running an Azure DevOps Server on premise.

We use the git repos and the artifacts nuget feed for our project.

Currently we do our builds (for the nugets) manually without the pipelines and upload the nugets later.

If we would use the pipelines the "Index sources and publish symbols" task would place the symbols to a file share.

So I have two questions:

Is there a way to upload the symbols manually (e.g. via CLI like we can with the nugets)?

Anywhere a documentation how the URL of the file share would look like on an on premise server? All examples I found so far only show dev.azure.com

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to upload the symbols manually (e.g. via CLI like we can with the nugets)?

The answer is yes.

You could use the push both primary and symbol packages at the same time using the below command. Both .nupkg and .snupkg files need to be present in the current folder:

```
nuget push MyPackage.nupkg -source
```

And publish to a different symbol repository, or to push a legacy symbol package that doesn't follow the naming convention, use the -Source option:

```
nuget push MyPackage.symbols.nupkg -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net/
```

Please refere the document for some more details:

[Publishing a symbol package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg#publishing-a-symbol-package)
[Publishing a legacy symbol package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages#publishing-a-legacy-symbol-package)

> Anywhere a documentation how the URL of the file share would look like
> on an on premise server?

You could check the document [Index Sources & Publish Symbols task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops):

[image]